# clearing last dumped text from terminal by flushing stdout

Tags: python, stdout, flush

Hi I kind of forgot in past I remember having done clearing out the last printed text in terminal doesnt seems to work how I am doing now

```
def main():

    print 'starting...'

    baseURL = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=%s' % myAPI
    print baseURL

    while True:
        try:
            RHW, TW, TWF = getSensorData()
            # LT = RCtime(RCpin)
            f = urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + 
                                "&field1=%s&field2=%s&field3=%s" % (TW, TWF, RHW))

            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write("Celcius: %s , Farenheit: %s , Humidity: %s "% (TW, TWF, RHW))
            f.close()


            sleep(int(myDelay))
        except:
            print 'exiting.'
            break
```

Can anyone please through some light ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you actually want to clear the screen **you should use curses or ncurses**

some hacks however are

- `\b` backspace character ... allows you to write over the last character
- `\r` carriage return without newline ... this will move the curser to the start of the current line in most terminals (allowing you to "overwrite" the current line) ...
- there are also some crazy hex escape codes that are very terminal specific

`os.system('cls')` or `os.system('clear')` will sort of work depending on your operating system

if you just want to `flush` the current `stdout` that is simply `sys.stdout.flush()`